# can help protecting or can help protect

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which one is correct?

> which can help in protecting childeren from ...

OR

> which can help protecting children from ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not grammatical to use an -ing form after the verb help without the preposition "in" before the -ing form.

So it's correct to say:

......which can help in protecting children from...

However, it's more common and idiomatic if you use an infintive with or without to after the verb help as follows:

.......which can help protect children from...

.......which can help to protect children from...